# Text baseline different on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text, baseline

I have the following CSS to control three `a` tags which should have vertically central text, however they appear at the top of the button. It's easier to see result.

CSS Code:

```
color: #fffae6;
border: 1px solid #fff;
outline: 4px solid #242424;
-moz-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
padding: 5px 0;
-webkit-transition: background 500ms ease-in-out;
background: #242424;
font-size: 1.7em;
display: block;
margin: 0 15px;
```

In chrome:
[image: Chrome's intepretation]

In IE:
[image: IE's interpretation]

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that css applied to anchor or button ?

Comment: Anchor tags, sorry I did mention in OP, " to control three `a` tags".

Comment: I think you'll have to specify more css ...Here this is what I created ...seems good to me : http://jsfiddle.net/aYtyx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use both the `height` and `line-height` property to achieve the same effect in IE.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pSM5L/)**.

Comment: Is my solution helpful for you?

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick although different versions of IE seem to render line heights differently so I've had to create more than one IE specific css stylesheet for the different versions of IE to set the different line-heights and heights.

Answer (score 0):

Please use line-height, as per your height of the button. I hope it will work

Comment: I have tried this, it only adds more space at the top and bottom so the text still remains in the top part of the button. Seems fine in IE8, but not IE11.